# Change a character Time of Day to a date in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need to extract the hour of the time of day in Redshift/Postgres from a character date of, for instance, 3:30 PM to 15:30:00. So, I need to go from 3:30 PM to 15:30 to 15.

Anybody got any pointers? Thanks

Comment: extract(hour from cast(timeedt as time)) as mentioned, I've also tried convert. SQL pops up with an error or:

INFO:  Function ""date_part"(text,time without time zone)" not supported.
INFO:  Function ""time"(text)" not supported.

ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
SQL state: 0A000

Answer (score 4):

Just cast it as time:

```
Select CAST('3:30 pm' as Time);
```

If you just want the hour then

```
Select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST('3:30 pm' as Time))
```

Example:

```
postgres=> Select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST('3:30 pm' as Time));
 date_part
-----------
        15
(1 row)
```

Comment: That works when I type in the date value, but for some reason it's not doing that for the column information that I'm pulling.

INFO:  Function ""time"(text)" not supported.

ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
SQL state: 0A000

Comment: Sounds like redshift is killing the query because of one of the functions used. Can you do the CAST without the EXTRACT and see if it lets it through? Maybe then you can just substring the first two characters off.